# expression expected at For F

Tags: vb.net

strTmp = value1 & For Each number As Integer In list.length-2    number     Next & Environment.NewLine & spltcomma(spltcomma.Length - 1) & value2 & value4 & Environment.NewLine & spltcomma2(spltcomma2.Length - 1) & strTmp.Substring(48)

Comment: Please copy-and-paste the code into the question and start each line with four spaces. As it is, we can't understand it.

Comment: As suggested, the code is unreadable as you posted it but the fact that you have a concatenation operator (`&`) immediately before a `For Each` means that that code can't possibly be right. Also, a question that contains just code is not a question. You need to take the time and make the effort to provide an actual explanation of the problem, which MUST include what you're actually trying to achieve. We shouldn't have to work that out from code that doesn't actually do it.